# g++: error: unrecognized option ‘--as-needed’

Tags: c++, g++

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with a gcc version 4.6.3. I am trying to build my code and getting an error when using 'make' command

```
g++: error: unrecognized option ‘--as-needed’
```

My Makefile looks as follows:

```
LFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath,. -Wl,-rpath-link,../bin --as-needed
LDFLAGS = $(RPATH) $(RPATHLINK)  -L$(USRLIB) --as-needed
```

Previously this code was successfully building on RedHat Linux. But now I need to run this code on Ubuntu.

If anyone knows about this. Please help

Regards
Gaurav

Comment: Did you try just deleting that flag?  Did you check your G++ or linker documentation to see if that flag is in fact supported?

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be -Wl,--as-needed ? Looks like an ld flag.

Comment: Related page: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/gnu-ld-as-needed.html

Answer (score 5):

@FatalError is right

And also better late than never answering this question.

you need to use `-Wl,--as-needed`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you had an extra space between the ld specifier "-Wl" and the option to be passed to ls "--as-needed". For the linker to get the extra option from g++ command, it should be "-Wl,--as-needed"